# Algorithm to “shoot” at a target in a 3d game

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, game-engine

For those of you remembering Descent Freespace it had a nice feature to help you aim at the enemy when shooting non-homing missiles or lasers: it showed a crosshair in front of the ship you chased telling you where to shoot in order to hit the moving target.

I tried using the answer from [AI algorithm to "shoot" at a target in a 2d game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107403/ai-algorithm-to-shoot-at-a-target-in-a-2d-game?lq=1) but it's for 2D so I tried adapting it.

I first decomposed the calculation to solve the intersection point for XoZ plane and saved the x and z coordinates and then solving the intersection point for XoY plane and adding the y coordinate to a final xyz that I then transformed to clipspace and put a texture at those coordinates. But of course it doesn't work as it should or else I wouldn't have posted the question.

From what I notice the after finding x in XoZ plane and the in XoY the x is not the same so something must be wrong.

```
    float a = ENG_Math.sqr(targetVelocity.x) + ENG_Math.sqr(targetVelocity.y) -
            ENG_Math.sqr(projectileSpeed);
    float b = 2.0f * (targetVelocity.x * targetPos.x + 
            targetVelocity.y * targetPos.y);
    float c = ENG_Math.sqr(targetPos.x) + ENG_Math.sqr(targetPos.y);
    ENG_Math.solveQuadraticEquation(a, b, c, collisionTime);
```

First time targetVelocity.y is actually targetVelocity.z (the same for targetPos) and the second time it's actually targetVelocity.y.

The final position after XoZ is

```
    crossPosition.set(minTime * finalEntityVelocity.x + finalTargetPos4D.x, 0.0f, 
                minTime * finalEntityVelocity.z + finalTargetPos4D.z);
```

and after XoY

```
    crossPosition.y = minTime * finalEntityVelocity.y + finalTargetPos4D.y;
```

Is my approach of separating into 2 planes and calculating any good? Or for 3D there is a whole different approach?

- sqr() is square not sqrt - avoiding a confusion.

Comment: I hope that there's no gravity here...

Answer (score 1):

If you're at `(0,0,0)` at time `t_0 = 0` and shoot a projectile with velocity `pv` and hit a target that has initial position `tp=(tpx,tpy,tpz)` and constant velocity `tv=(tvx,tvy,tvz)` at time t, that means that

```
Abs(tp+t*tv) == t*pv
```

Solving this equation for t (tp*tv is the scalar product of tp and tv, etc):

```
t = - (tp*tv ± sqrt((tp*tv)^2+(tp * tp)*(pv^2-tv*tv))) / (tv*tv-pv*pv)
```

So you need to shoot at the position `tp+t*tv`. Just project that into your viewport and draw your crosshair there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why the `Abs`? Isn't `tp + t*tv == t*pv` generally true?

Comment: We use the absolute value because we're computing the *distance* between the target and the shooter at time *t* (which has to be equal to the distance travelled by the bullet in order for the bullet to hit at that time).

Comment: @Gareth Rees: Oh, I see the problem - I read `pv` as a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The equations for the 3D case are the same as [I gave in the 2D case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4124965/68063). The only difference is that the firing solution isn't in the form of an angle: you need a 3D rotation. But for this application, you don't need a firing solution, you just need to know where to draw the reticule.

For example, taking the simplest case (a stationary shooter which can rotate instantly):

Let the target be at the position A and moving with velocity VA, and the shooter be stationary at the position B and can fire bullets with speed *s*. Let the shooter fire at time 0. The bullet hits at time *t* such that |A − B + *t* VA| = *t s*. This is a quadratic equation in *t*, which you should be able to solve (or determine that there is no solution). Having determined *t*, you can now draw your reticule at the screen position corresponding to the world position where the bullet will hit (which is A + *t* VA).

The other cases are similar, just as in 2D.