# How does the math behind target-prediction intersection work?

Tags: game-physics, 2d-games

So currently, I am working on a tower defense game and tried out both techniques- HOming and missile/target intersection prediction p-- for firing missiles to hit the target.

Aesthetically, I like the latter method better because it seems seamless. The problem is that I basically just copied the math from the 2nd post of this thread
[2d game : fire at a moving target by predicting intersection of projectile and unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248876/2d-game-fire-at-a-moving-target-by-predicting-intersection-of-projectile-and-u), and I honestly haven't got a clue how the dude formulated this equation.

I have some background in math and understand what a quadratic formula is but what I don't understand is how he came up with it. I googled some sample quadratic formula problems but the problems seem either too simple or irrelevant.

*Can anyone direct me to a book or site that will help me understand this math a bit better?*

Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary to post your question IN ALL CAPS unless it's an acronym or abbreviation (like XML, for instance). Posting CAPITALIZED TEXT makes it harder to read, it's annoying, and at times it's considered SHOUTING (which is rude). Properly cased text is easier to read and understand, and posting IN CAPS won't get you an answer any sooner. Thanks.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your browser or computer, because my questions are not all written in caps.

Comment: I edited your subject to remove the caps (`NOT HOMING`). pst further edited it to remove the words I fixed. I didn't say "all written in caps". I said please don't use caps when they're inappropriate, as in if I USED THEM NOW. The edit history for this question shows where the caps were, and where I edited to remove them. :-)

Comment: My bad, I must have not been paying attention when I wrote the title in all caps, becuase I usually never do that/understand it can be annoying.

Comment: This is stuff is basic kinematics and vector math.  Pick up any high school physics text book, or google some information kinematics and you should see the solutions he came to are nothing special. Good luck, I know this stuff can be tough when you don't know what to look for.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad my browser and computer are working OK. :-)